# dijit.form.ComboBox not working with dojox.data.JsonRestStore

Tags: javascript, rest, dojo

I have my store defined as follows:

```
my_store = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({
    target: '/my/rest/url/to/get/data'
});
```

And I defined ComboBox to work with that store:

```
myComboBox = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
    store: my_store,
    searchAttr: "name",
    pageSize: 20,
    autoComplete: true,
    hasDownArrow: false,
    highlightMatch: "all",
    style: "width: 80%; height: 17px; float: left",
    onChange: function () {
        // Do something with my tree
    },
    labelFunc: function (item, store) {
        var splits = item.path[0].split("/");
        var label = item.name[0] + " ("
            + splits.slice(0, splits.length - 1).join("/") + ")";
        return label;
    }
}, "searchBox");
```

But I can't make it working. ComboBox doesn't show anything.
But when I use `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` it works fine.

Could you please suggest any solution?
BTW, I need to use JsonRestStore because I do lazy loaded tree with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the network tab in your browser's console to verify if the rest call is happening. May be fully qualified url is required. Ex: 'http://localhost//my/rest/url/to/get/data'

Alternatively you can use dojo.xhrGet to return the Json result and create  dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore out of that. This will also load the combobox when you actually do the ajax call.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yep, url is loaded and returns data, but nothing is happened without additional steps. I've created Memory store to work with ComboBox and filled it with data retrieved by the JsonRestStore. It helped.